# django javascript translation with simple interpolation

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, interpolation

The [documentation for javascript translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#using-the-javascript-translation-catalog) in django only gives examples of pluralised interpolation. I want to do something simple like below:

```
var format = gettext("Displaying %(count)s / %(total)s")
var text = interpolate(format, {"count": 5, "total": 10})
```

which should set `text` to `Displaying 5 / 10`

But this isn't working for me. I get `Displaying %(count)s / %(total)s` as the value for for `text`.

Does anyone know how to do this simple sort of interpolation?

Comment: You're missing `true` argument: `interpolate(format, {"count": 5, "total": 10}, true)`.

Comment: ah yes I see, I was looking at the non-named interpolation example on the django docs. Perfect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing `true` argument:

```
var text = interpolate(format, {"count": 5, "total": 10}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

And without named = true, you can do:

```
var format = gettext("Displaying %s / %s")
var text = interpolate(format, [5, 10]);
```